# Reduction of methylene blue

Tags: chemical-biology

Why does methylene blue (which is initially blue) reduce to form a colorless solution?

I was told by my teacher that it has to do with the presence of an additional double bond on methylene blue, but I can't figure out or find any source on the internet that claims so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The color change results from the reversible oxidation-reduction reaction of the methylene blue indicator.  In alkaline solutions, glucose is oxidized to D-gluconic acid or alpha-D-gluconolactone.

$\ce{HOCH2(CHOH)4CHO + 3OH- -> HOCH2(CHOH)4CO2 + 2H2O + 2e-}$

In the course of this reaction, methylene blue is reduced from the blue (oxidized) form to the colorless (reduced) form.

[image]

Shaking the flask dissolves $\ce{O2}$ in the solution, which oxidizes the indicator back to the blue (oxidized) form.

Comment: Okay, but does the presence of extra double bond has anything to do with colour change?

Comment: Can you expand on how the presence of double bond leads to colour change?

Comment: Sure ! The double bond changes its position in the product , which is due to tautomerisation. Now , since tautomers  have different physical properties , they have different color. One reason for this is , the lone pairs of Nitrogen which were earlier undergoing conjugation at one side , now undergo conjugation from both sides , resulting in decreasing the electron density on N . Since , it becomes harder for N to donate electrons to the solvent , it now shows different spectral behaviour and hence different color .

Comment: Is the same reason applicable for the colour change on methyl orange due to breaking of double bond between the nitrogen ?

Comment: Yes !  You're correct.